# Is there a daemon, service, utility, or program for automatically keeping track of local file content hashes?

Tags: file, hash, service, daemon

We have a large number of files (~2,000,000), on a local disk, that we'd like to keep tabs on.

An idea is to get a hash (MD5 is the first thought, though the particular algorithm isn't that important to us) of each file's individual contents, and then periodically check if the content (and hence the file) has changed by re-hashing and comparing the hashes.

This is relatively straight forward to do, but doing it in the most efficient and/or disk-friendly way would take effort. Before we build this, we'd like to know that nothing off-the-shelf exists.

We are wondering if there is a daemon, or service, or other utility or program we could start up, and point at a directory tree, that we could then later somehow query to get the hash of a file or set of files of interest at that time? Ideally these queries would return instantly, certainly we would hope they would be much faster than reading and hashing the entire file (or set of files) in question.

We have done some cursory searches, but the keyword space is polluted by recent (interesting!, but irrelevant here) activity around `ipfs` and other distributed file systems that also care about file content hashes.

The machine is Ubuntu, if that helps, though, relevant software for any OS would be interesting to know about.

The total size of all the files is ~50TB, and the sizes vary from a few bytes up to several GB.

Of course, file timestamps and modification dates will be considered and used in our larger system, but in particular we're interested in tracking changes to file contents, modification dates can easily change without any content changes e.g., `touch`...

Comment: I don't know of anything that will automatically traverse your directory structure, but one simple idea I had to quickly query your file hashes is to run something like md5sum -b * >md5filehashes.txt on each directory, then you can get the hash from the last time the program ran with something like grep somefile.txt md5filehashes.txt. You'll have to run md5sum -b somefile.txt to get the current value of course, to see if it has changed. I suspect what you really want is something to report only those files which have changed though, so I think you may need to write a simple program.

Comment: @SimonGoater - thanks for this thought, and you're definitely on the right track. What I'm after is a daemon, service, utility, or other program that would do what you describe (though maybe it would use a database instead of flat files scattered in the relevant directories), and that could serve queries about the hashes to the whole system (several other programs). Since there are millions of files and tens of TB of data I want to hash it all as infrequently as possible. Do you know if there is any such program?